# select with multiple where condition in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
sno    col1    col2    col3    col4
-----------------------------------
A1      55      12      35       8
A2       6      15      21       6
A3      55      15      22       7
```

I want to select `Sno` and `col1`, `col2`, `col3`, `col4` WHERE col1, col2, col3, col4 are BETWEEN -10 AND 100

How should I use multiple conditions in `where`?

Comment: please share your progress

Comment: i got my answer @zaratustra was correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select Sno, col1, col2, col3, col4
  from YOUR_TABLE
 WHERE col1 BETWEEN -10 AND 100
   and col2 BETWEEN -10 AND 100
   and col3 BETWEEN -10 AND 100
   and col4 BETWEEN -10 AND 100
```

Comment: thank you my friend it work perfectly its strange because i used the same code last night i got error incorrect syntax near BETWEEN but now it worked! i think i was sleepy :)) thanks alot!